# table - No border collapse

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

In my layout, I have a table who take all the screen:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_with="fill_parent"
    androidlayout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
        <TextView
            ... />
        <TextView
            ... />
        <TextView
            ... />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
        <TextView
            ... />
        <TextView
            ... />
        <TextView
            ... />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
        <TextView
            ... />
        <TextView
            ... />
        <TextView
            ... />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

In my example, the borders are collapsed, but I want some margin between the borders in width and height of document.
How can I do this?

Comment: I want some margin between row and cols borders of my table. Like, for example, on default html css table.